# Convergence of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f_n$ and $g_n$ are a sequence of continuous functions on $D\subset \mathbb R^m$ and the sequence

$$\{a_n\}= \{ \int_D f_n + i g_n dx \}$$ converges and also that $$\{b_n \}= \{ \int_D |f_n| + i |g_n| dx \}_n$$ converges.

Does it follow that
$$\{ \int_D |f_n + i g_n| dx \}_n$$  converges?

Comment: Well I am assuming the individual integrals all exist, I just don't know if there is convergence.

Comment: My first comment was daft, so I deleted it. However, you should choose another index for these sequences.

Comment: Okay, hopefully that's better

Comment: Are $f_n,g_n$ real-valued?

Comment: Yes, real valued but may blow up.

Comment: Maybe I can just say $| |f_k + ig_k| - |f_j + ig_j| | < | |f_k | - |f_j|  |+ | |g_k | - |g_j| |$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: On $[0,1],$ let $f_n = 2\chi_{[0,1/2)}, g_n = 2\chi_{[1/2,1]}$ for odd $n.$ For even $n,$ let $f_n=g_n=1.$ Then $f_n,g_n\ge 0$ and $\int_0^1f_n= \int_0^1g_n = 1$ for all $n.$ So both $a_n,b_n$ converge. However

$$\int_0^1 (f_n^2+ g_n^2)^{1/2} = 2$$

for $n$ odd, while

$$\int_0^1 (f_n^2+ g_n^2)^{1/2} = \sqrt 2$$

for $n$ even.

---

EDIT: I edited the answer to make it simpler.